# How to recognize tap on imageView when it on Table View (Custom Cell)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

hwy buddy i try to make my album view for that i put my 3 imageView on custom cell than after i set all images but i can`t tap on that image.... if i can tap/touch that image than i saw particular image on New View and make photo album like application.... please Help me.....

Thanks In Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make them UIButtons instead of UIImageViews? they will look exactly the same but you can attach event handlers to them in interface builder (or in code if you want).

Comment: but when i click on image  didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method Called it not recognize Tap/Touch...

Comment: ok it`s work but i dont get indexPath.row that`s why now i can`t recognize which button click....But thanks for this idea if u have an idea than tell me how can i also recognize indexPath.row

Comment: Can you post some code in your question? Why do you need to know indexPath.row if you have three buttons on one row?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I mistook it,but already fixed:try overwrite the `hitTest:withEvent:` method of your cell view, check the type and target of the touch event with `pointInside:withEvent:`, if returns yes, then you got it

Comment: but when i click on image  didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method Called it not recognize Tap/Touch...      I dont get Your point be clear... Please

Comment: I mistook the sendEvent: with hitTest:withEvent:, now it's fixed. See if it helps.